# Saving/renaming a project and preview files

Tags: premiere, preview

If I save Adobe Premier Pro (CS6) projects under different names as I go along to mark my progress, are the preview files in the associated folder no longer used?

For example, if I save a project as: "video v1.prj", and then render some video in the edit window, and then save it under a different name as "video v2.prj" does premier use any pre-rendered files in the old directories?  Or can I delete those pre-rendered files if I'm no longer using that version of the project without causing any data loss other than any pre-rendering for that particular project version?

Answer (score 1):

If you rename a project it continues to link to the old preview files. Any new preview files Premiere creates are saved in a new folder with the updated project name. So you'd be using media from two different folders at that point.

If you delete the old preview files then Premiere will just re-render them when needed.

I tested this by creating a project called **test**, adding some clips and applying effects and rendering. Render files were created on my scratch disk in a folder called **test.PRV**. Then I saved the project as **test-rename**. When I closed and reopened it the clips I had rendered still had the green bar above them, and played back fine, though at this point there was no **test-rename.PRV** folder in my preview folders.

If I moved the original render file from the **test.PRV** folder and re-opened the **test-rename** project the bar went red. When I rendered it the resulting file was saved in a new **test-rename.PRV** folder. QED.

Note that Premiere gets confused if you remove the render files while the project is open. It doesn't realise that the preview files are missing, and behaves erratically.

Comment: I just want to add that you can re-link rendered preview files as well. At least with premiere pro cc, when I delete the folder with the preview files and then open the project, it prompts me to re-link the preview files just like missing media. Not sure if this applies to cs6 as well though